# Python.h not found even after I used sudo install

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I've been studying darkflow from the following link;
https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow 
on Ubuntu 20.04
I thought there was a problem in my flow file, so I tried to rebuild the build file by the following code

```
dyi@D-FIP7VAE:~/Tiny-YOLO-voc-traffic-sign-detection$ python3.7 setup.py build_ext --inplace<br/>
```

and this is what i got.

> setup.py:6: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
> import imp
> running build_ext
> building 'darkflow.cython_utils.nms' extension
> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-ZE4Yn0/python3.7-3.7.10=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-ZE4Yn0/python3.7-3.7.10=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/dyi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c darkflow/cython_utils/nms.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/darkflow/cython_utils/nms.o
> darkflow/cython_utils/nms.c:29:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
> 29 | #include "Python.h" 
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~ 
> compilation terminated. 
> error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

so I tried this

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

But this didn't work, and I get the same error over and over.
Can anybody find the reason why..?

Comment: Check if `python3-dev` is actually for `3.7`: `sudo apt-cache show python3-dev`. If not see if you have `python3.7-dev` available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
sudo apt install libpython3.7-dev
```